# Why is matplotlib taking so long to plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm reading two files.txt , each one has about 50,000 rows and I'm saving the data in some list and trying to plot later, but the plot is not loading.

Here is my code

```py
xeqt = []
yeqt = []
xv = []
yv = []
with open('graficoEQT.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.strip()
        x,y = i.split(" ")
        xeqt.append(round(float(x),3))
        yeqt.append(y)

with open('ErroValidacao1.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        i = i.strip()
        x,y = i.split(" ")
        xv.append(round(float(x),3))
        yv.append(y)

plt.plot(yeqt, xeqt, color = 'blue')
plt.plot(yv, xv, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Why is it taking so long? How could I solve this?

PS: This is not a duplicate because my question is about the time that my plot is taking and not because the plot is wrong.

Comment: this is because your are reading file line-by-line. Try to use, e.g. `numpy.loadtxt`, or `pandas.read_csv(sep='\s')`; Also, you can sparsify your array, e.g. `yv = numpy.array(yv)[::3]`,  `xv = numpy.array(xv)[::3]`.

Comment: Thanks, I read with pandas and it's work.

Comment: @LarissaTeixeira: If you comment out the plotting lines, does our code still takes similar time? If yes, then reading the files is the culprit. In that case, try using my answer using `loadtxt` and let me know if you get some speed up

Comment: @Sheldore I commented the plot lines and reading the files was very fast. But when I try to plot, it does not work. I read the file with pandas and it works. I can not explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems not in the plotting but reading the file using a for loop and then splitting each line. Instead, you can make use of `loadtxt` from NumPy to read in the values into two variables.

**Importantly**, `plt.plot` will join all the data points by lines. This could in principle be one of the reasons for long time. You can try using a `scatter` plot instead.

You did not share the data so I can't test the speed. Nevertheless, you should try the following

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xeqt, yeqt = np.loadtxt('graficoEQT.txt', unpack=True)
xeqt = np.round(xeqt, 3)

xv, yv = np.loadtxt('ErroValidacao1.txt', unpack=True)
xv = np.round(xv, 3)

plt.scatter(yeqt, xeqt, color = 'blue')
plt.scatter(yv, xv, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: @PeterWood: Done, in the comments above. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to convert your strings to numbers. When plotting strings each string will get its own text label on the axis. This makes a long time to render.

Either `yeqt.append(float(y))` (same for `yv`) or you use any of the tools available that do the conversion automatically, like `pandas.read_csv` or `numpy.loadtxt`.